# Docker exec rpc error code =13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: cannot exec a container that has run and stopped\n"

Tags: docker, centos

I have `rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: cannot exec a container that has run and stopped\n"`
when  i do `docker exec -it containerID bash` but the container is up and answering to http requests. 
On the same computer (linux/centos7) two other containers are up and working well..

Comment: post `docker logs container_pb` and `docker events` also, the host OS, `docker info`  and `docker version`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the image you are using to start the container is not supported for underlying hardware architecture.